# TaxonomyWebTaggingControl losts vaule when selecting a term from suggestions

Tags: 2013, 2010, taxonomy

I'm using a TaxonomyWebTaggingControl on a custom application page. The problem is, when I type in some chars into the controls textbox I get a correct list of suggestions. When I select a suggestion, the selected term is set in the textbox and is underlined. That means everything is valid and ok.

This is the result after selecting a term from the suggestions list

[image]

When i do a post back now (click on button) the selected value is gone and my control is empty! but i am able to type in chars and getting a correct list of suggestions.

[image]

When I select a term through the picker control the term is selected also...

[image]

[image]

but this time the value stays after post back in the textbox and is validated.

[image]

This is my **CODE:**

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(SPContext.Current.Site);
        InitTaxonomyWebTaggingControl(txSBU, taxonomySession, "SBU");
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void InitTaxonomyWebTaggingControl(TaxonomyWebTaggingControl control, TaxonomySession session, string dimension)
    {
        control.GroupId = session.DefaultKeywordsTermStore.Groups[MIATermGroupName].Id;
        control.SspId.Add(session.DefaultKeywordsTermStore.Id);
        control.TermSetId.Add(session.DefaultKeywordsTermStore.Groups[MIATermGroupName].TermSets[dimension].Id);
        control.AllowFillIn = true;
        control.IsIncludePathData = true;
        control.IsMulti = false;
        control.Language = session.DefaultKeywordsTermStore.DefaultLanguage;

    }
```

Why is my term lost when I select the term through suggestions and why is everything after post back there when I select the term through the picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my testing I have detected the problem: `control.IsIncludePathData = true;`

When you select from suggestions, `control.Text` contains something like this:

```
label | GUID| GUID | GUIDSELECTED
```

When you select from picker, `control.Text` contains:

```
label | GUIDSELECTED
```

So, you can avoid the problem with `control.IsIncludePathData = false`, or assigning the correct value in `control.Text`.